# ignore non-existant files when merging in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge

I am working with a repository with stable and experimental branches.  Sometimes I add a file on the experimental branch that is not yet ready for the stable branch.  When I merge, I want to merge the changes in the files that are common to both branches, but ignore the files that don't exist on one of the branches.

Here's a simple example:

```
hg init
hg branch stable
(create file A)
hg add A
hg commit -m "Added A"

hg branch exp
(create file B)
hg add B
hg commit -m "Added B, which is really experimental"

(modify file A)
hg commit -m "Some changes to A"

hg update stable
hg merge exp
```

However I change the merge tool configuration, Mercurial always seems to take B along with the merge.  Since it doesn't exist on the stable branch, it's never a conflict.

I could do the following:

```
hg update stable
hg merge exp
hg commit -m "Merged"
hg revert -r 0 B
```

but that requires me to know which files need reverting.

Any thoughts on the simplest way to make the merge ignore files that don't exist on one branch, and preferably do it automatically?

Comment: Mercurial is doing exactly what you told it to. You told it take your changes on the `exp` branch and merge them into the `stable` branch. That includes new files. Were you trying to instead merge changes in `stable` over to `exp`?

Comment: Maybe you should think about your branch concept and use a third branch for *really-experimental* changes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask Mercurial to do what you want.

You do not merge individual files, you merge the entire branch, which means that all the files that are part of the branch becomes part of the merge. This is how Mercurial is designed and how it operates.

Now, you *could* revert/forget/delete the files you don't want before you commit, but then you're just setting yourself up for disaster later.

I recommend you separate things you want to keep from things you don't know if you want to keep so that you can merge one branch and let the other be separate for now.